# Is the use of 'event attribute on non-clock signal bad practice?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035461/is-the-use-of-rising-edge-on-non-clock-signal-bad-practice-are-there-alternativ), which was answered with

> Yes, `rising_edge()/falling_edge()` should only be used for clock
>   signal. While it works in simulation it can cause problems and
>   unintended hardware in synthesis.

Is the same thing true for using the `'event` attribute to detect edges of non-clock signals like in the following example?

```
process (rndm_sig)
begin
    if (rndm_sig'event and rndm_sig = 1) then
    -- do something.
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Here, you define the same thing as `if rising_edge(rndm_sig) then` ! In synthesis, `rndm_sig` will be considered as a clock signal.

Comment: Yes, but if `rndm_sig`  is say a signal from a input port then this signal would have to be connected to a clock buffer, which would, according to the other thread, lead to a error during synthesis, correct? My question basically is: Is the same true for using `'event`?

Comment: Whether you say `rising_edge(some_signal)` or `some_signal=1 and some_signal'event` is utterly irrlevant. In both of these `some_signal` will be connected to the clock input of a flip-flop and is, therefore, a clock.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem, honestly, a detected edge in digital design is meaningless unless it's either a clock or the edge can be expressed in relation to the clock that will use the decision of the detected edge. In the first case, your question is invalid, in the second there's no reason to use 'event if you have a clock that fulfills Nyquist and the third option is that you're not doing pure digital design, which means you shouldn't be using an FPGA (which you tagged).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any signal used as `X'event and X= 1` or `rising_edge.(X)` will be treated by the synthesis tool as a clock.

In an FPGA that means the routing tool will try to assign a dedicated clock net to the signal, with all that it entails. e.g. the signal has to be routed to a dedicated clock input which can cause significant delay and skew against the other signals.

Also the signal had better be 'clean'.  It means that a FF will clock if there is the tiniest spike on the signal. It also means that if your signal is not 'clean', some FFs may trigger and some may not.

The timing tool will need to know the period and high/low time and try to make the set-up and hold time work against all other clocks. This can cause major problems and/or extra logic in the design. If the signal is totally asynchronous against the other clocks you can have meta stability and may need to add synchronizers after the clocked register(s).

So it comes down to: it is ***strongly recommended*** to use only 'real' clock signals for the `X'event and X= 1` or `rising_edge.(X)` constructs.

At the same time there is one rule in digital design which says: all rules are out if there is no other solution.

<sub>In the ASIC industry, where I come from, you had to talk to some senior designers before you broke the basic rules. Then you had to add some big emphasized comment around the code stating *"Yes this breaks the rule but there was no other way because we had this and this and this and it has been reviewed and signed of by X and Y "* And yes, I once used a latch in a design.</sub>